# Printer Recommendation for CAD drawings

Tags: printer

I create parts using MasterCam software (https://www.mastercam.com/en-us/). Essentially this is CAD/CAM software and I would like to buy a better printer than the one I have. I dont need a plotter.

Here are my requirements:

Minimum:
 - 11x17
 - Laser
 - Ability to print higher detail

Preferred:
Color

My budget is less than $1,000.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Hardware Recommendations, it generally helps us make better recommendations if you can give us an upper price limit/budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be very difficult to find a Laser printer under $1000 that comes in as large a size as A3 (11.7 x 16.5 in). I was only able to find a Refurbished/Used - Like New system.

### [HP Color LaserJet Professional CP5225dn $500.00 + $54.59 shipping](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004433XCQ)

[image: CP5225dn]

- Resolution: 600 DPI
- Rate: 20 Pages per minute (ppm)
- Technology: Laser (non-LED)

If your current printer already prints as 600 DPI or higher, you probably shouldn't upgrade unless you find that this printer's PPM is faster than your current printer and worth the upgrade. I would still suggest [purchasing a brand new one ($1660)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004433XCQ) if you have the money.

*It appears the link is automatically redirecting to the full price page.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following Color Ink Jet printer for printing my color and B&W 11" x 17" CAD drawings: HP DESKJET 1220C PARALLEL USB PRINTER
While this is not a laser printer its prints are of good quality.

There is currently one for sale on eBay for $125 plus shipping.
https://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-DESKJET-1220C-PARALLEL-USB-PRINTER-USED/123299758165?epid=1800332047&hash=item1cb53d0055:g:SOoAAOSwNDFba1kR

Best regards, Bob